Why is Swagger UI not showing my endpoint with a specific name?
I have a mysterious behaviour in Swagger UI
When I name an endpoint "IDCard" it is not showing up in Swagger UI (the endpoint IS callable through Postman though!):



However, if I name it "IDCar" or "IDCarod" it IS showing up:




Does anyone have a clue here what this could be? Are there any Swagger log files I can check?
Thank you in advance!

Which version of Swagger are you using? How are you configuring swagger? I cannot replicate your scenario.

Show us your Startup class (or other equivalent program code) - and how you've declared your Controller classes. Please also share the exact names and versions of all Swagger/NSwag/Swashbuckle/OpenAPI packages you're using.

In the future please post code as text not images. Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Found the solution. There was an IDocumentFilter that removed the path.
